# missing JSON array SWIFT

Tags: ios, json, swift, get, swift4

There is a code generated by Insomnia and it works:

```
import Foundation

let headers = [
  "x-auth-header": "fb2f56fde81f21926fc0b5b74702f71da9f152efa7b5587a308984b71c9acac7fd44da05583ab06d57d29794f59fc475d9f2d132cbc6e29c421f11330a30a613",
  "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]

let postData = NSData(data: "".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://rekrutacja.backendzs.pl/note/")! as URL,
                                        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.httpBody = postData as Data

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    print(error)
  } else {
    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    print(httpResponse)
  }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

It works and has to return the array of items:

```
[
    {
        "note_id": 14,
        "title": "last one",
        "content": "maybe",
        "version": 16,
        "created": 1530825998,
        "modified": 1530825998
    },
    {
        "note_id": 13,
        "title": "again",
        "content": "again",
        "version": 15,
        "created": 1530825532,
        "modified": 1530825532
    },
    {
        "note_id": 12,
        "title": "zzz",
        "content": "zzzz",
        "version": 14,
        "created": 1530825484,
        "modified": 1530825484
    },
    {
        "note_id": 11,
        "title": "Nowy tytuł",
        "content": "4",
        "version": 13,
        "created": 1530825331,
        "modified": 1530825331
    },
    {
        "note_id": 10,
        "title": "test5",
        "content": "test",
        "version": 12,
        "created": 1530825252,
        "modified": 1530825252
    },
    {
        "note_id": 9,
        "title": "title7",
        "content": "1111",
        "version": 11,
        "created": 1530825225,
        "modified": 1530825225
    },
    {
        "note_id": 7,
        "title": "test",
        "content": "content",
        "version": 9,
        "created": 1530817192,
        "modified": 1530817192
    },
    {
        "note_id": 6,
        "title": "Tytuł",
        "content": "Treść",
        "version": 8,
        "created": 1530550847,
        "modified": 1530550847
    },
    {
        "note_id": 5,
        "title": "Tytuł",
        "content": "Treść",
        "version": 7,
        "created": 1530547099,
        "modified": 1530547099
    },
    {
        "note_id": 3,
        "title": "title",
        "content": "content",
        "version": 3,
        "created": 1530469102,
        "modified": 1530469102
    },
    {
        "note_id": 2,
        "title": "title",
        "content": "content",
        "version": 2,
        "created": 1530468369,
        "modified": 1530468369
    }
]
```

However, it doesn't provide this list with the response from the server. Only general data is displayed. I've tested and checked every article related to Alamofire, swiftyJSON, Swift .get requests and none of them works.

Considering this information:

1. The connection with the server is being established (code)
2. If to launch the generated "shell" code and run through the "terminal"
   (Mac OS) it returns the array.
3. Incorrect parsing? If yes - how to extract this data?

Tried Dictionaries, swiftyJSON, NSSession ... but I did something wrong for sure. I'm dealing with JSON at SWIFT first time, so I can do silly mistakes!

Thanks to everyone who will try to help in advance!!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You print content inside `httpResponse` , You need to use the data returned with `Decodable`

```
struct Item : Decodable {

 let title:String,content:String,version:Int,created:Int32,modified:Int32,noteId:Int

  private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case title,content,version,created,modified,noteId = "note_id"
  }


}
```

//

Inside response completion

```
do {
       let items = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
       print(items)
}
catch {
    print(error)
 }
```

Comment: Type 'Item' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
Declared the structure before class but it has some errors ._. already searching about this, thank you)

Comment: Maybe it should be just "struct" or "extension" with parameter "Decodable"? Duo to the documentation of Apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: It works now, without commas. MAN! LET THE GODS BLESS YOU!))) You've solved the problem I tried to fix for several days in 5 minutes ._. Thank you from the heart!

Comment: Happy Coding =D